# Why does cron log to auth.log every 30 minutes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cron

I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu with these cron settings, four jobs running once a day:

```
10 6 * * * cd $HOME/...
30 4 * * * mongodump ...
30 4 * * * . .bashrc && ...
10 4 * * * cd $HOME/...
```

The authlog at `/var/log/auth.log` shows these:

```
Apr 10 18:17:01 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[24761]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 10 18:17:01 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[24761]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 10 18:40:01 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[24888]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user bitnami by (uid=0)
Apr 10 18:40:01 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[24888]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user bitnami
Apr 10 19:17:01 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[25146]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 10 19:17:01 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[25146]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 10 19:40:01 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[25261]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user bitnami by (uid=0)
Apr 10 19:40:01 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[25261]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user bitnami
Apr 10 20:17:01 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[25523]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 10 20:17:01 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[25523]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 10 20:40:01 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[25642]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user bitnami by (uid=0)
Apr 10 20:40:02 ip-172-26-9-252 CRON[25642]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user bitnami
```

Why does `cron` log in and out of a session every 30 minutes?

Comment: Run `ls /etc/crontab /etc/cron.d/` and check the files it prints.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That's it! It shows two tasks, one running every hour at minute 40, another running every hour on minute 17. Do you want to write an answer?